# Vim folder listing, can't reach :

Tags: vim

In Vim's folder viewing mode I can't enter the : state for I get error:

> Error detected while processing BufWinEnter Auto commands for "*"
>
> E32: No file name

How do I fix that error?

[Here's my vimrc.](http://synodins.com/unix/vim/vimrc)
Except I now have commented out the BufWin's.

I've stopped looking for this solution for now as I have managed to disable folder viewer.
For that see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13510941/disableing-vims-folder-view).

Comment: Your questions are hard to answer without more context. Re-reading your question, try to put yourself in the role of potential readers: What information would they need? Here, a list of defined `:autocmds` would be helpful.

Answer (score 2):

You seem to have copied an autocmd into your configuration that is too simple and doesn't handle situations like unnamed buffers well.

If this is related to your [other question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13509533/vim-file-direction-e739), I'd suggest you have a look at http://vim.wikia.com/wiki/Make_views_automatic, where (in the comments section), multiple solutions to make the automatic view creation more robust are discussed.

Otherwise, go through the list of `:autocmd BufWinEnter`, try to find the culprit, and either fix it or remove that functionality.

Comment: I have already commented all BufWinEnter in my vimrc, that got my ':' from displaying an error to opening a new tab. But I actually wanted to enter ':'

Comment: This really is a world of nightmares where fuzzy incomprehensible errors pop up apparently randomly, usually requiring extensive studies of tedious, poorly explained technical details all living humans would prefer not to have to waste their lives on. I am content living without folder viewer.

Comment: Hm, that "tab opening" is very strange. You may also have interactions from whatever plugins you have installed. Since the problem is easy to reproduce, I would try a binary search, i.e. disabling (renaming) half of your plugins in `~/.vim/plugin/`, then the other half, ... The same can be done with parts of your `.vimrc`.

Answer (score 1):

You should be able to get out of this by doing:

```
:q
```

in the same way as you would quit from a file? Perhaps you need to add '!'

Comment: Since that's the case then I have rephrased the question.

Comment: Do you have anything in your vim config that is referencing BufWinEnter?

It looks like 'something' is trying to be automatically executed on entering vim, and that command is expecting a filename.You can normally enter a '?' to only match when a file exists, but you'll need to find the command being executed first.

Comment: yes there is, and if I remove it I don't get that error in folder view anymore. But instead of entering : mode it just apparently creates new tabs all the time.

Comment: And I really dont want to disable the BufWinEnter functionality anyways, it automatically moves you to wherever you left the file last time, which is really great.

Comment: Can you post the command line - you should be able to add a '?' in-front of the * to ignore the line when there is no filename.

Comment: theres nothing on the command line, i just press ':' and an extra tab gets created.

Comment: Sorry, I meant; is it possible to post the relevant sections of your vim config that refer to BufWinEnter.

Comment: Yes that's the first BufWin reference in the vimrc file I posted in the question.

Comment: OK, sorry I missed that. Just add `*.*` instead of `*`, for example: `au BufWinLeave *.* mkview`