# Disableing Vim's folder view

Tags: vim

When I enter Vim's folder view I always enter trouble, as you can see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13510406/vim-folder-listing-cant-reach).

Is it possible to simply disable this folder View?
So that I never have to enter it again by accident.

And if so, how do I do that?

Comment: `:Ex` is too damn useful, fix your `autocmd` issue instead. Besides, how would you type `:Ex<cr>` by accident?

Comment: I travel directly into files using a shortcut to gf.. a lot. And it happens quite regularly that im editing real fast and then bamm... that file listing horror again. Must restart terminal and delete a bunch of registers wether I like it or not. Besides, I think i can largely program my way around it or even make my own folder searcher in little more time than it takes to learn how to live with all those extra bugs.

Comment: Again, fix your `autocmd` problem. Go back to your other question and show us your vimrc so that we can help you. If you *really* *really* *really* want to get rid of `netrw` there's no option to put in your vimrc I know of: just go to your `$VIMRUNTIME` and delete the `netrw.vim` file.

Comment: Which folder is my $VIMRUNTIME?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The "folder view" is provided by the *netrw* plugin (cp. `:help netrw-intro-browse`) that is included in the default Vim installation. You can disable it by putting

```
:let g:loaded_netrwPlugin = 1
```

into your `~/.vimrc` file. However, your *real* problem is bad `:autocmds` that do not handle so-called *scratch buffers* (i.e. artificial buffers that do not correspond to an actual file, but are used to display plugin functionality). You'll probably encounter similar problems with other plugins, too, so rather fix or remove those autocmds! Disabling *netrw* is just working around the problem.

Comment: Epic, that lets me avoid entering that folder listing.

Comment: This really is a world of nightmares where fuzzy incomprehensible errors pop up apparently randomly, usually requiring extensive studies of tedious, poorly explained technical details all living humans would prefer not to have to waste their lives on. I am content living without folder viewer and I still haven't seen a need for any plugin so I can just happily live without them for now.

Comment: The power of Vim comes from its flexibility; that's the price you occasionally have to pay. Usually, such "nightmares" are related to a recent change you've done; some people put their entire `.vim/` directory under version control for that reason; it makes it easier to locate the problem.